# starting service on systemd won't terminate

Tags: upstart, systemd

Created an executable and planned to use it as service.

When running it on Ubuntu 12.04 or 14.04 using upstart, it works fine.

However, on Ubuntu 15.04 (with systemd), this command won't not terminate:

```
systemctl start mySrv01
```

Could it be because I didn't close stdin?  upstart doesn't seem to mind.
Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Didn't have to do this when using upstart, don't know why.

You don't have to do it with systemd, either.  You have a readiness protocol mismatch.  Your service unit file says that your program employs the `Type=forking` readiness protocol.  But your program itself actually did not.

The `forking` readiness protocol is hard to get right, and easy to get wrong.  Almost no program in the wild actually employs it.  Just make your service unit `Type=simple` if that's what it already was to start with.

Moreover, you don't need to muck around trying to "dæmonize" by doing things like closing open file descriptors.  Your program *is already dæmonized*.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/200365/5132
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). [*You really don't need to daemonize. Really.*](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/systemd-house-of-horror/daemonize.html).  The systemd House of Horror.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out for systemd,  the daemon process mySrv01 will have to fork a child process and better off, close stdin.

Didn't have to do this when using upstart, don't know why.