# Systemd service not working

Tags: server, 16.04, systemd

I just switched to 16.04 server from 14.04 server. With Upstart I used to start my server with a file that I had in /etc/rcS.d called M95. M95 was called by /etc/rc.local. Now with systemd I have written a file in /etc/systemd/system called my.service. It looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=MyService

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/etc
ExecStart=/bin/sh rc.local

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I type "/bin/sh rc.local" into the command line my server does start.
When I try to start the service by doing "systemctl start my.service" nothing happens.

The relevant lines in journalctl -b are:

```
Started MyService.
eth0 ...(basically the info I see from ifconfig)
root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/etc ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/etc/rcS.d/M95
pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
$File not found:: /new/den-routes
udhcpd already running
pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
/bin/rm: cannot remove '/var/log/rewriting-net-rules': No such file or directory.
```

In rc.local it looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
...
sudo /etc/rcS.d/M95
/bin/rm /var/log/rewriting-net-rules

exit 0
```

In M95 it starts udhcpd (which is where the "udhcpd already running" message comes from) and at the end starts the server by saying:

```
cd /new
/bin/sh StartServer&
```

It seems that it does get to M95 because messages are getting logged from it, but the server does not start. When I run these files in the command line it works, but as the service it does not work. I am very unfamiliar with systemd so I have no idea if I am doing this correctly. For a week I have been reading examples and tutorials for it but I am still unsure how this works and how the service file should be written.

Edit: Here is my StartServer file:

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup /jre/jdk1.8.0_101/jre/bin/myserver -Xrs -Xmx1000m -jar /new/MyServer.jar nowd &
```

It runs just fine when I start it from the command line. It runs when I call it from my.service. I put in some echos to see that it gets through the whole file, but myserver and MyServer.jar don't start for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the problem was in a piece of code in rc.local. A line that someone put in trying to remove a file would produce an error and cause the program to exit if the file didn't exist. I am not sure why it did not produce this error when I ran it in the command line, but when run using a service, it stopped everything from working.

I fixed it by adding an if statement to check if that file exists before I try to remove it.

Comment: Little late now, but an 'if' statement is not necessary.  Just add a -'f' option to the 'rm' command.  If file does not exist, no error.

Answer (score 4):

My goodness, there are a lot of things wrong here.

- You aren't running your service directly; but instead your service unit is running a shell that interprets `rc.local` in working directory `/etc`.  This despite the fact that systemd has a pre-supplied service unit for running `/etc/rc.local` if one really wants to.  (`rc.local` is a mechanism that has been superseded three times over on Ubuntu, first by van Smoorenburg `rc`, then by upstart, then by systemd.)
- But `/etc/rc.local` isn't running your service either.  Instead it is invoking `sudo`, despite the fact that it is *already* running as the superuser.
- That's in turn running a (second) script from `/etc/rcS.d`, despite the fact that directory is a symbolic link farm that isn't supposed to contain actual `rc` script files.
- That script runs by hand dæmons that systemd is clearly already running as actual services.
- It thinks that the working directory should be `/new` not `/etc`.
- But even that isn't your service.  Instead it is forking a shell to interpret a third script named `StartServer`.
- It's not using `exec` to overlay itself.
- It's using `&` to run that shell asynchronously.
- That fourth script is then forking and running a Java program.
- It too is not using `exec` to overlay itself.
- And the icing on the cake is that that is *also* using `&` to run that Java program asynchronously.

None of this is necessary.

And you appear for no apparent reason to have plonked it in the middle of a mechanism for re-setting MAC addresses in cloned virtual machines.

```
[Unit]
Documentation=https://askubuntu.com/a/831314/43344
After=udhcpd.service

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/new
ExecStart=/jre/jdk1.8.0_101/jre/bin/myserver -Xrs -Xmx1000m -jar /new/MyServer.jar nowd

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

There's also clearly an `After=` addition needed for whatever it is that is writing out the `den-routes` file that your dæmon is expecting; you, however, not providing any information to determine what that is.

### Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015).  [*The systemd House of Horror*](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/systemd-house-of-horror/).  Frequently Given Answers.
- https://askubuntu.com/a/674133/43344
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194653/5132
- https://askubuntu.com/a/626858/43344
- Warren MacEvoy (2010-10-24). *[How to clone an Ubuntu virtual machine without changing 70-persistent-net.rules?](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1045715&page=2&p=10017557#post10017557)*.
- Chris Stuccio (2011-12-03).  *[Networking problems while cloning Ubuntu VM](https://chrisstucchio.com/blog/2011/network_problems_cloning_ubuntu_vm.html)*.

Comment: Very professional

Comment: I changed the service file as you suggested. It still does not work. So I will add an edit showing my StartServer file.